# User Control in XAML only shows name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to use user controls in XAML, after a while and several tutorials I managed to get it "working" (read 'it builds without errors'). However when I run it, all I can see (instead of 2 test labels) is the name of the Class.

Here's my code:
Usercontrol:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Config.UCTest">
  <Label Text="TEST" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">TEST</Label>
  <Label Text="TEST" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="150,10,10,10">TEST</Label>

</Grid>
```

Codebehind usercontrol:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Config
{
    public partial class UCTest : Grid
    {
        public UCTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Mainwindow :

```
<Window x:Class="Config.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Config.WPF"
        xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Config;assembly=Config"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" Height="154" Width="363">
    <control:UCTest/>
</Window>
```

Codebehind Mainwindow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Config;
using System.IO;

namespace Config.WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, "Config" isn't the namespace used in the actual project, there's a prefix so it's not referring to a C# Config namespace. I deleted the prefix to 'hide' the source project.

As you might notice too, the MainWindow and the usercontrol are in different projects, but it picks it up as it should. When I wrote an error in the user control, the mainwindow gave an error on the line where the usercontrol is imported. Also the full name and namespace is shown in the mainwindow. So they do know of eachother. But I can't seem to be able to show the actual controls in there.

Comment: Have you tried setting your control `Height` and `Width` values?

Comment: Yes, tried that one, but getting "The BindableProperty "Height" is readonly" error

Comment: As I'm a beginner in all things concerning XAML I followed a tutorial, tutorial used a grid. It compiles fine. It runs. It just doesn't act how it's supposed to.. Tried other things too, but they didn't even do anything. I'm completely open to other approaches, as long as it starts to work :)

Comment: @Lonefish Have you tried just building the project that contains the UserControl. It should have build errors.

Comment: It doesn't have any build errors.. Using Xamarin too, maybe that changes things? Also, about the text property not existing : http://i.imgur.com/S13zDgD.png Intellisense actually hands me the Text property. Deleted it, doesn't change things tho.

Comment: Remove the VertiacalOptions and HorizontalOptions as well. WPF Label don't have those and try again.

Comment: @R.Rusev op is using Xamarin. Xamarin Label have those

Comment: @Pikoh Yes you are right, I just checked, it's not so much a wpf question then.

Comment: That explains why I was able to use Text too I presume?

Comment: Yes Lonefish, Xamarin is slightly different from wpf. In wpf `Label` has the `Content` property, in Xamarin has the `Text`one

Answer (score 2):

User Control

```
 <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-  compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
        <Grid>
           <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <TextBlock Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0"></TextBlock>
              <TextBlock Text="TEST" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" ></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <controls:UserControl1 Width="200" Height="200"></controls:UserControl1>
  </Grid>
 </Window>
```

[image]

With Usercontrol in different project.

first create wpf user control library project and add usercontrol in it. same code as above.

then add the project reference into the main project.

```
 <Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    xmlns:WpfControlLibrary1="clr-namespace:WpfControlLibrary1;assembly=WpfControlLibrary1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <WpfControlLibrary1:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="120" Width="172"/>

    </Grid>
 </Window>
```

Comment: What are you deriving UserControl1 from in codebehind?

Comment: Apparently we're not going to use user controls after all.. Thanks for the help tho.

Answer (score 0):

The derivation of your UserControl is not correct.

```
public partial class UCTest : UserControl
{
    public UCTest()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```